# Zoom on brush in horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my code below I've managed to make the brush move in unison with the zoom event, but I'm now stuck with trying to make the bar chart zoom properly when you use the brush.

I've based my `brushed` function on [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46017299/7473025) answer but was unable to convert the logic to my own code.

I get the error: **Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined** and I have no idea why.

Here's all my code:

```js
const data = [
 {month: "jan", value: 12},
 {month: "feb", value: 25},
 {month: "mar", value: 10},
 {month: "apr", value: 15}
];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
 margin = {top: 10, right: 35, bottom: 10, left: 35},
 width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var g = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", 
  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// === Bar ===

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
 .range([margin.left * 2, width])

var y = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(data.map(d => d.month))
 .range([height, 0])
 .padding(0.1)

var yAxis = g => g
 .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left * 2},0)`)
 .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSizeOuter(0))

g.append("g").selectAll(".bar")
 .data(data).enter().append("rect")
 .attr("fill", "steelblue")
 .attr("class", "bar")
 .attr("x", x(0))
 .attr("y", d => y(d.month))
 .attr("width", d => x(d.value) - x(0))
 .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

g.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y-axis")
 .call(yAxis);

// === Brush ===

var xB = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
 .range([0, margin.left]);

var yB = d3.scaleBand()
 .domain(data.map(d => d.month))
 .range([height, 0])
 .padding(0.1);

var brush = d3.brushY()
 .extent([[0, 0],[margin.left, height]])
 .on("start brush", brushed);

var yAxisB = g => g
 .call(d3.axisLeft(yB).tickSizeOuter(0))

g.append("g")
 .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(brush)
  .call(brush.move, yB.range().reverse())

g.append("g").selectAll(".brushBar")
 .data(data).enter().append("rect")
 .attr("fill", "steelblue")
 .attr("class", "brushBar")
 .attr("x", xB(0))
 .attr("y", d => yB(d.month))
 .attr("width", d => xB(d.value) - xB(0))
 .attr("height", yB.bandwidth());

g.append("g")
 .call(yAxisB);

// === Brush & Zoom ===

var bExtent = [[0, 0], [width, height]]

var zoom = d3.zoom()
 .scaleExtent([1, 2])
 .translateExtent(bExtent)
 .extent(bExtent)
 .on("zoom", zoomed)

g.append("rect")
 .attr("class", "zoom")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
 .call(zoom);

function zoomed() {

 if (d3.event.sourceEvent && 
  d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;

 var t = d3.event.transform;

 y.range([height, 0]
  .map(d => d3.event.transform.applyY(d)));

 g.selectAll(".bar")
  .attr("y", d => y(d.month))
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

 g.selectAll(".y-axis").call(yAxis);

 g.select(".brush").call(brush.move, 
  yB.range().reverse().map(t.invertY, t))
}

function brushed() {

 if (d3.event.sourceEvent && 
  d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return;

 var s = d3.event.selection,
  nD = [];

 yB.domain().forEach((d) => {
  var pos = yB(d) + yB.bandwidth() / 2;
  if (pos > s[0] && pos < s[1]){
   nD.push(d);
  }
 });

 y.domain(nD);

 g.selectAll(".y-axis").call(yAxis);

 g.selectAll(".bar")
  .attr("y", d => y(d.month))
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

 //g.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
 // .scale(2)
 // .translate(-s[0], 0));
}
```

```css
.zoom {
 cursor: move;
 fill: none;
 pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="540" height="120"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not getting the error you described.

The problem in your snippet seems to be that the brushed out bars are piling up at the top of the SVG. This is due to the fact that you're changing the `y` scale's domain, and because of that some bars get `undefined` for `y(d.month)`. Therefore, instead of nicely disappearing from the view, they are simply painted at `0` in the `y` position.

The best alternative is rethinking all your brush/zoom code. However, for minimal changes in the code, a quick and dirty solution is simply turning the bars that have `undefined` for the `y` position transparent:

```
.style("opacity", d => y(d.month) ? 1 : 0)
```

Also, make the `pointer-events: none;` for the bars in the brush, that makes a better user experience:

```
.attr("pointer-events", "none")
```

Here is your code with those change:

```js
const data = [{
    month: "jan",
    value: 12
  },
  {
    month: "feb",
    value: 25
  },
  {
    month: "mar",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    month: "apr",
    value: 15
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 35,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 35
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// === Bar ===

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()
  .range([margin.left * 2, width])

var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.month))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1)

var yAxis = g => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left * 2},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSizeOuter(0))

g.append("g").selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data).enter().append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", x(0))
  .attr("y", d => y(d.month))
  .attr("width", d => x(d.value) - x(0))
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis")
  .call(yAxis);

// === Brush ===

var xB = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
  .range([0, margin.left]);

var yB = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(d => d.month))
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1);

var brush = d3.brushY()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [margin.left, height]
  ])
  .on("start brush", brushed);

var yAxisB = g => g
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yB).tickSizeOuter(0))

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(brush)
  .call(brush.move, yB.range().reverse())

g.append("g").selectAll(".brushBar")
  .data(data).enter().append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("class", "brushBar")
  .attr("pointer-events", "none")
  .attr("x", xB(0))
  .attr("y", d => yB(d.month))
  .attr("width", d => xB(d.value) - xB(0))
  .attr("height", yB.bandwidth());

g.append("g")
  .call(yAxisB);

// === Brush & Zoom ===

var bExtent = [
  [0, 0],
  [width, height]
]

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 2])
  .translateExtent(bExtent)
  .extent(bExtent)
  .on("zoom", zoomed)

g.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "zoom")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(zoom);

function zoomed() {

  if (d3.event.sourceEvent &&
    d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;

  var t = d3.event.transform;

  y.range([height, 0]
    .map(d => d3.event.transform.applyY(d)));

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .attr("y", d => y(d.month))
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

  g.selectAll(".y-axis").call(yAxis);

  g.select(".brush").call(brush.move,
    yB.range().reverse().map(t.invertY, t))
}

function brushed() {

  if (d3.event.sourceEvent &&
    d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return;

  var s = d3.event.selection,
    nD = [];

  yB.domain().forEach((d) => {
    var pos = yB(d) + yB.bandwidth() / 2;
    if (pos > s[0] && pos < s[1]) {
      nD.push(d);
    }
  });

  y.domain(nD);

  g.selectAll(".y-axis").call(yAxis);

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .attr("y", d => y(d.month))
    .style("opacity", d => y(d.month) ? 1 : 0)
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

  //g.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
  // .scale(2)
  // .translate(-s[0], 0));
}
```

```css
.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="540" height="120"></svg>
```

Comment: I commented out the error code, should've mentioned that, but your solution will have to do for now. I'll look more into creating better brush/zoom code